# Send array of JSON objects with TNetHTTPRequest.Post()

Tags: delphi, httprequest

I need to send a post request containing JSON like this:

```json
[ { "sku": "AS12AS11S", "estoque": 3}, { "sku": "ASKD123F4", "estoque": 10} ]
```

I have found examples inserting a single JSON object.  How can I set the params to send more than one JSON object?

This is the actual code that I have.

```pascal
var
  NetHTTPClient : TNetHTTPClient;
  parametres : Tstringlist;
begin
  parametres := tstringlist.Create;
  NetHTTPClient := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);

  parametres .Add('nom_logiciel='+UTF8Encode('éè'));
  parametres .Add('emplacement='+EncodeURIComponent('éè') );
  parametres .Add('version='+ 'éè');

  NetHTTPClient.ContentType := 'application/json';
  NetHTTPClient.AcceptEncoding := 'UTF-8';

  NetHTTPClient.post('http://metaclients.xxx.fr/xxx',parametres,nil,TEncoding.UTF8).ContentAsString(tencoding.UTF8);

  parametres .Free;
  NetHTTPClient.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the overloaded version of `TNetHTTPClient.Post()` that takes a `TStream` as input rather than a `TStrings`.  Then you can store your JSON into a suitable `TStream` as needed, such as `TStringStream`.

```pascal
var
  NetHTTPClient : TNetHTTPClient;
  parametres : TStringStream;
begin
  NetHTTPClient := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    NetHTTPClient.ContentType := 'application/json';
    NetHTTPClient.AcceptEncoding := 'UTF-8';

    parametres := TStringStream.Create('[{"sku": "AS12AS11S", "estoque": 3}, {"sku": "ASKD123F4", "estoque": 10}]', TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      Result := NetHTTPClient.Post('http://metaclients.xxx.fr/xxx', parametres).ContentAsString(TEncoding.UTF8);
    finally
      parametres.Free;
    end;
  finally
    NetHTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```